# Get Date from googlesheets and create a counter in javascripts that counts days past

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

Is it possible to get value from a Google Sheets cell that contains a Date and count on another cell how many days have past since that date in JavaScript?

The problem is that when you are coding in JavaScript it is not easy to do numeric calculations with dates that you get from cells. So if I do the following it does not work correctly

```
function myFunction() {
   var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet()
   var start_date=ss.getRange(2,14).getValue()
   var today=new Date(new Date().getFullYear(),new Date().getMonth(), new Date().getDate())
   var difference=today-start_date
   ss.getRange(2,14).setValue(difference)

}
```

The date at the targeted cell is 4/12/2019

and The result that I get is 3786824092000

Comment: Is this mili seconds difference ?

Comment: I think now you need to divide this number with 24*60*60*1000 to get number of days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your code to read/write in Google sheet is correct. Below code should work for you.

```
var start_date = new Date(ss.getRange(2,14).getValue());
var today=new Date(new Date().getFullYear(),new Date().getMonth(), new Date().getDate())
var difference= (today-start_date) / 86400000;
ss.getRange(2,14).setValue(difference)
```

Comment: If I do that I get the result: 25/1/1900

Comment: Logger.Log for difference is giving me 26 which is the correct but in the cell I get 25/1/1900...